# Dynamically assigned IDs

Tags: javascript, gmail, protractor

**The Goal:** Navigate through Gmail, and click on a link that in my inbox.

**So far I have:** Logged into gmail with username and password successfully as well as opened up the first displayed email using Protractor.

**The issue:** Each time I load the webpage and inspect the HTML code in order to reference the link in the email, the class names and ids are different. For instance, last time the xpath was: `//*[@id=":6d"]/a`, but now it is `//*[@id=":ml"]/a`.

**The element:**
`<a href= "the desired link" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="the desired link v2" > change Account password.</a> == $0`

And all superclasses above it consist of code like the following: `<div id=":66" class="ii gt adP ad0>` which are seemingly dynamically created.

How would you all recommend referencing the link?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider using [gmail.js](https://github.com/KartikTalwar/gmail.js/), it might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `by.linkText` and `by.partialLinkText` are the two most relevant locators:

```
element(by.partialLinkText("change Account password")).sendKeys("test");
```

(make sure the letter case is correct).